# Asus ROG GL552VW backlit keyboard driver issue - ububtu 20lts

Tags: keyboard, asus

i just purchased an asus ROG GL552VW laptop but can't find the driver that turns on the backlit keyboard. in windows it's called: atk package.

Answer (score 0):

You need the latest kernel. Do you have 5.6 or 5.7 ?

If not look at this : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Ant this could help too :
Automatic : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-kernel-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux
Manual : http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-kernel-5-5-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to compile the Linux kernel to your PC. The problem is not a package missing but a bad address on the kernel header (drivers/hid/hid-ids.h). According to apeelme at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194557, the solution is to change the according line:
`-#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x1837`
`+#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x8176`

This steps could make your distro unbootable. Backup all your data first.

To compile the kernel, first download the latest stable kernel from kernel.org. Then extract the folder and open a console inside it and run the following commands:

## Install kernel build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

## Go to drivers/hid/hid-ids.h, and replace the line

`#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x1837`
with
`#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x8176`

## Build the kernel (it will take some time depending on your pc)

`make -j $(nproc)`

## Install the kernel and its modules

```
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

Now your keyboard should work. If not, uninstall this kernel.

This was tested and it's working on Asus ROG GL553VW with Debian 10 and with the current latest stable Linux kernel (5.9.7)